# SQL query for MySQL that will fetch usernames and their last comments from the database (one comment per user)

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a SQL query to MySQL, which will select usernames and their last comments from the database (one comment for each user), with the following table structure (SQL query should also display users who have no comments):

```
CREATE TABLE `db_user` (
  `db_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `db_comment` (
  `db_comment_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `db_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db_comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Created 2 tables and entered some values ​​into them:

CREATE TABLE `db_user` (
`db_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`balance` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`db_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `db_user` (`db_user_id`, `name`, `balance`) VALUES ('1', 'Pavel', '5,5');
INSERT INTO `db_user` (`db_user_id`, `name`, `balance`) VALUES ('2', 'Alex', '6,7');
INSERT INTO `db_user` (`db_user_id`, `name`, `balance`) VALUES ('3', 'Maria', '7,8');
INSERT INTO `db_user` (`db_user_id`, `name`, `balance`) VALUES ('4', 'Mike', '4,3');

CREATE TABLE `db_comment` (
`db_comment_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`db_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`text` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`db_comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('3', '1', 'Hello!');
INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('2', '2', 'Beatiful!');
INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('1', '3', 'What?');
INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('3', '4', 'Amazing!');
INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('2', '5', 'Nice!');
INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('1', '6', 'Cool!');
INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('3', '7', 'Great!');
INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('2', '8', 'OMG!');
INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('1', '9', 'Really?');
INSERT INTO `db_comment` (`db_user_id`, `db_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES ('4', '', '');

Then I tried to write a SQL query:

SELECT
u.name,
c.text
FROM `db_user` u
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT
Db_comment.db_user_id,
MAX(Db_comment.db_comment_id) as last_cid,
FROM `db_comment`
GROUP BY db_comment.db_user_id
)uc ON u.db_user_id=uc.db_user_id
LEFT JOIN `db_comment` c
ON c.db_comment_id=uc.last_cid

But there are many errors.
I'm a beginner in writing SQL queries, please tell me how to make such a query more correctly and easier.

Approximate result:

1 Pavel - Really?
2 Alex - OMG!
3 Maria - Great!
4 Mike -        , (or post a line "No comments")

Comment: Why not provide some sample data too

Answer (score 0):

```
trying to answer but still have some issues, work in progress, interested by support too ^^


db_comment_id    db_user_id    text
1                1             Hello
2                2             Great
3                3             Awesome
4                1             NextStage
5                2             Crazy
6                1             Horrible`

________________________________________________________________________________

db_user_id    name    balance
1             joe     200.00
2             jane    350.00
3             bill    80.00
    
________________________________________________________________________________

select last_comment.*, name
    FROM db_comment last_comment

LEFT JOIN db_user ON db_user.db_user_id=last_comment.db_comment_id
LEFT JOIN db_comment new_comment
    ON last_comment.db_user_id = new_comment.db_user_id
    AND last_comment.db_comment_id<new_comment.db_comment_id
WHERE new_comment.db_user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY last_comment.db_user_id DESC LIMIT 3

________________________________________________________________________________

OUTPUT
db_comment_id    db_user_id    text        name 
3                3             Awesome     bill
5                2             Crazy       null
6                1             Horrible    null
```